# Ruby on Rails. Waveform audio gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, audio, web, rubygems

Does anybody knows any audio gem with waveform generation and popular formats support? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There's a waveform gem for precisely that:

https://github.com/benalavi/waveform